# Android&SOAP I can't send and response the data

Tags: java, android, soap

I'm trying connect Android with SOAP by use ksoap2 project. Earlier I compiled a few project and they work correct.

WSDL File: http://pastebin.com/AjX08eFE

I checked it by using SoapUI - it's working.

My fragment Java code: http://pastebin.com/dQzu9VPM
Of course, ksoap2 library .jar is added to project.

When I run app, I get message:

```
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214): SoapFault - faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Server' faultstring: 'Procedure 'getNameWithAge' not present' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:137)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:301)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:274)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at eu.webnitro.nrpdfqrcodescanner.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:135)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19873)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
07-01 23:57:29.193: E/MYAPP(7214):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
07-02 00:12:05.433: I/Timeline(7214): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1b4ca974 time:3247127
```

I tried various options, and I got various messages. I don't have any idea how I can fix it.